# Не компилируются примеры из книги Opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv

Всем привет! Кто-нибудь юзал книгу O'Reilly: Learning OpenCV Гари Рост Брадски и Эйдриан Калер?
Я не могу понять, поему часть примеров из этой книги спокойно запускается, а часть нет.
Например вот этот пример компилируется нормально:

```
#include<QApplication>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;


int         g_slider_position   = 0;    // Позиция ползунка
CvCapture*  g_capture           = NULL; // Структура для видеофайла

// Вызывается каждый раз, когда происходит изменение положения ползунка
//
void onTrackbarSlide( int pos ) {
    // Установка свойства: положение
    //
    cvSetCaptureProperty(
         g_capture
        ,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES
        ,pos // Номер кадра
    );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     QApplication app(argc, argv);

     cvNamedWindow( "TrackBar", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );    // Создание окна
     g_capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "/home/sergey/Загрузки/Bell.avi" );         // Открытие видеофайла для формирования структуры

     // Получение кол-ва кадров
     //
     int frames = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(
          g_capture
         ,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT
     );

     if( 0 != frames ) {
         // Создание ползунка
         //
         cvCreateTrackbar(
              "Position"         // Имя ползунка
             ,"TrackBar"         // Окно для вывода ползунка
             ,&g_slider_position // Начальная позиция
             ,frames             // Максимальная позиция
             ,onTrackbarSlide    // Функция обработчик
         );
     }

     IplImage* frame; // Кадр

     while(1) {
         frame = cvQueryFrame( g_capture );    // Последовательное чтение кадров

         if( !frame ) {                      // Конец файла, кадров больше нет
             break;
         }

         cvShowImage( "PlayVideo", frame );  // Отображение кадра
         char c = cvWaitKey(33);             // Ожидание 33 мс, получение ASCII кода клавиши

         if( c == 27 ) {                     // Если Esc - выход из цикла
             break;
         }
     }
     cvReleaseCapture( &g_capture );   // Закрытие файла
     cvDestroyWindow( "PlayVideo" ); // Уничтожение окна
    return app.exec();
}
```

А вот этот нет:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

void TransformImg( IplImage* image )
{
    cvNamedWindow( "Transform-in" );    // Окно для отображения исходного изображения
    cvNamedWindow( "Transform-out" );   // Окно для преобразованного изображения

    cvShowImage( "Transform-in", image );

    // Создание контейнера для преобразованного изображения
    //
    IplImage* out = cvCreateImage(
         cvGetSize( image )
        ,IPL_DEPTH_8U
        ,3
    );

    // Сглаживание
    //
    cvSmooth( image, out, CV_GAUSSIAN, 3, 3 );

    // Отображение результата преобразования
    //
    cvShowImage( "Transform-out", out );

    // Высвобождение выделяемой памяти
    //
    cvReleaseImage( &out );

    // Ожидание нажатия клавиши для завершения программы
    //
    cvWaitKey( 0 );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Transform-out" );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Transform-in" );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("/home/sergey/Загрузки/icon.jpg"); // Получение имени изображения
    TransformImg( img );                                             // Преобразование исходного изображения
    cvReleaseImage( &img );                                          // Освобождение памяти из под изображения


    return a.exec();
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
:-1: ошибка: main.o: неопределённая ссылка на символ «cvSmooth»

/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.3:-1: ошибка: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

:-1: ошибка: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit stat
```

Что за выборочная компиляция? Что-то компилируется, а что-то нет!

Хотя в файле .pro все одинаково:

```
QT -= gui
QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Что за проблема такая?

Comment: `-llibopencv_imgproc` пропущена в `LIBS`'ах

Answer (score 2):

Компилятор указывает на то, что не может найти реализацию функции `cvSmooth()`.

Вообще, эта функция объявлена устаревшей. Из [документации по OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=cvsmooth#smooth):

> Функция является устаревшей. Используйте вместо неё `GaussianBlur()`, `blur()`, `medianBlur()` или `bilateralFilter()`.
>
> ---
>
> The function is now obsolete. Use `GaussianBlur()`, `blur()`, `medianBlur()` or `bilateralFilter()`.

Возможно, эта функция была удалена из новых версий OpenCV или перемещена в какую-то отдельную библиотеку совместимости.